# Javascript loop task with integers

Tags: javascript

I'm new to learning javascript. I have tried watching youtube videos to help me on this. However, I'm having no luck trying to find a solution to complete this task.

The task is to write a program that reads a value from the user and displays the even numbers between 1 and the value provided by the user.

I'm finding the selectional statement and the loop part very hard to understand. could someone guide me through completing this task please?

```
var nums = prompt ("Please input a number")

var evens = [];

var evenNumbers = function(nums) {
for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
  if 
  else

evenNumbers(nums);
alert(evens);
```

Comment: You don't need an array unless you wanted to collect the results. Your `for` loop can start with `i` at `1`, and then the condition can be `i <= nums` *(not `nums.length`)*. Then inside the `for` loop, display the current `i` value if it is evenly divisible by `2`, or `.push()` it into the array.

Comment: weekend is over now they are looking for a solution for their assignment

Comment: Your edit dramatically changed your question.  I don't even know what it is anymore.  Suggesting revert.

Comment: @SandyGifford question rolled back to revision 1. Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the modulus operator. It gives you the reminder value of the division. As the logic says that if a number is divisible by 2(reminder == 0) that number is even.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp

```
var nums = prompt ("Please input a number")

var evens = [];

var evenNumbers = function(nums) {
for (var i = 0; i <= nums; i++) {
    if (i % 2 === 0)
    {
      evens.push(i)
    }
  }
}
evenNumbers(nums);
alert(evens);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `nums.length` will bring you the length of the string from the user.
You need `var nums = parseInt(prompt ("Please input a number"));`. This assumes the user enter a valid number.

Then, use the for loop:

```
for (var i=2; i<nums; i=i+2){
     alert (i);
}
```

1) 1 is not an even number, so you can start at 2.

2) Since every 2 numbers there's an even number you can just jump strait to them (that's why the i=i+2).

3) If you want to check if a number is even you can use the modulo function:

```
if(i%2 == 0)
    alert (i);
```